# How to make a query with optional keys of an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know how to find a user through their email address, since my schema is a bit special

This is my user schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    private: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    data: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

I tried to make the query like this... but it does not work

```
const user = await User.findOne({
  email: {
    data: req.body.email,
  },
})
```

is there any way to make the private key optional?

Comment: try `{ "email.data": req.body.email }`

Comment: throws an error ```CastError: Cast to string failed for value \"{ data: 'email@email.com' }\" at path \"email.data\" for model \"User\"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like this if you want optional query

```
let query = [];
if(req.body.email)
query.push({ "email.data" : req.body.email})
if(req.body.private)
query.push({"email.privte" : req.body.private});

const user = await User.findOne({$or:query})
```

for the question answer is :

```
const user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ 'email.data': body.email}]
```

Comment: thank you,  ```const user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ 'email.data': body.email}]``` is what I was looking for